# How to copy content from broken card

Tags: file-transfer

I need to copy 50Gb info from 64Gb broken flash card. Sometimes I need to ask Windows 10 system to retry copy the same file for several times. How to achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried the Windows native error correction tool already? If not then why not? Really, it's a no-brainer.

Comment: So most of the files are still readable? Did you try running `chkdsk` as administrator?

Comment: The simplest method would be to just bin the card & copy from your backup to a new one. They're not worth the effort once they start to play up.